# Get only the page name from a subpage url in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I installed Lua support and the Module:String module in MediaWiki and I'm trying to get only the second half of a link in a template.

template: Icon

`{{Icon|Icon.png|mypage/Mysubpage}}` would return a link to the subpage while only showing "Mysubpage" and not the complete link "mypage/mysubpage"

The normal template looks like this:

```
[[File:{{{1}}}|{{{size|64px}}}|link={{{2}}}|{{{2}}}]]<br>{{#ifeq:{{#pos:{{lc:{{{2|}}}}}|http}}|0|[{{{2}}}]|[[{{{2}}}]]}}
```

But now that I'm adding subpages, the icons show the complete link path next to them.

I tried to replace {{{2}}} with:

```
{{#invoke:String|sub|{{{2}}}| {{#invoke:String|find|{{{2}}}|/|1}}+1 |{{#invoke:String|len|{{{2}}} }} }}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Huh just found `{{#titleparts:}}` buried in the docs. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension installed, the [`{{#titleparts}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23titleparts) magic word might be helpful.

The [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23titleparts) say:

> This function separates a page title into segments based on slashes, then returns some of those segments as output.
>
> ```
> {{#titleparts: pagename | number of segments to return | first segment to return }}
> ```
>
> If the number of segments to return parameter is not specified, it defaults to "0", which returns all the segments from the first segment to return (included).
>
> …
>
> Negative values are accepted for both values… Negative values for the first segment to return translates to "start with this segment counting from the right":
>
> `{{#titleparts: Talk:Foo/bar/baz/quok | | -1 }}` → `quok` Returns last segment.

Since you are looking for only the last segment, you want `{{#titleparts: {{{2}}} | | -1 }}`. This will work whether or not the template is used on a subpage.